# unable to connect to wireless connection

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, unix

Look at [this question in Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643319/unable-to-connect-to-wlan0-kali).
You may tell me to ask the question in a more appropriate community.

But, this is not a easy question for me. When I was searching on Internet I didn't get any related solution to this.

When my laptop becomes hotter and hotter I lose the wireless connection. In my other post I was saying that it is working in Windows, but not in Linux.

When I lost wireless the connection in Linux, I restarted laptop immediately. I also noticed that I didn't get a wireless connection in Windows.

I am not adding any pictures or anything because, my laptop isn't overheating yet.

So, I will add some further information when I lose my wireless connection again.

When I was writing the question I found a similar post, this is the question in superuser. [In this answer](https://superuser.com/a/116887/1293740), the poster recommends to remove wireless card.

But, how can I remove wireless card?

The wireless card: Intel Centrino **Advanced-N 6205**

[image: information]

[image: I have lost connection now]

```
Lenovo
Compliance ID: TP00018A
20V==3.25A/4.5A
Canada ICES/NMB-003 CLASS/ClassB
FCC ID:QDS-BRCM1046
CANADA IC: 4324A-BRCM1046 
TYPE : 4291-ZFV S/N R9-MTMV1 12/03 
PRODUCT ID: 4291ZFV
MEID: A1000004B1DE
IMEI : 356569041307500
```

It's been 3 hours laptop is keep running today it's hotter enough also. But, Wireless connection is work well. I didn't make any changes...

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I added a picture. I am not sure which you want to know.!

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I have edited my question. I have lost connection again..! Let me add model.. I have edited again!.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I have edited my question again.. Look

Comment: “Look at [this question in Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643319/unable-to-connect-to-wlan0-kali). You may tell me to ask the question in a more appropriate community.” Why should we do that? You have a richer question over there and it gets solid comments as well as answers. Why are you — effectively — reposting that question here. Voting to close.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is effectively a cross-post of the same poster’s other question on [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/643319/30848).

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I am not on laptop that's why I can't be sure which version is this. I only remember that it is latest of kali-linux. I have already unloaded **comat-wireless** I don't remember I load it again or not. So, are you saying that I should remove/load it again.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Unix SE is for Linux. And, superuser is for windows. This issue is very unique if someone can solve it from windows than how Unix user can help? So, I want to solve it from Linux or Windows both will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After editing this question, and reading your cross-post.
(try not to cross-post... It is frowned upon in both SE communities.)

You have indicated in the other post that you are a beginner.

Here is what I would recommend:

- **CLEAN YOUR LAPTOP** cooling system of any dust, dander or debris, pet hair etc.
  (You indicated it drops out when it heats up, this will probably lead to failure of hardware if you allow it to run like this.)
- Use a Distribution that is a little easier on beginners to learn the Linux system. Ubuntu or Lubuntu would be a good choice. Lubuntu is better for **older hardware**, as it is **much lighter as far as resources are concerned**. Both of these distributions can easily add all of the tools from the kali repository, leaving you with a system that is both a daily driver, and capable of allowing you to learn penetrating testing.
- If you insist on using Kali Linux, reformat your Linux partition with the latest  Kali rolling release 2021.1 (it takes about 20-30mins to install) it looks like the networking system is broken from the use of obsolete drivers. I know for a fact the advanced-n and ultimate-n family of wireless cards work "out of the box" in the latest Kali version.

If you follow these instructions, and the wifi card is still dropping out, then it should be replaced. You can find them on ebay pretty cheap.

Comment: I have used Ubuntu, mint, fedora earlier. And, my Kali version is 2021.1